# laravel won't run on ubuntu server

Tags: laravel, apache, virtualhost, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server

this is my first time using ubuntu server and i want to give it a try. I already did the apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin install, and VirtualHost setup. And I already download my program from github on `/var/www/html/project/`. Usually when I run redirect my VirtualHost to `/var/www/html/project/public` laravel would automatically start, but instead i got show a coding from `/var/www/html/project/public/index.php`. What did i do wrong?

to setup VirtualHost first I type `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/project.dev.conf` and type this code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.dev
    ServerAdmin project@dev.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and then on terminal I typed `sudo a2ensite project.dev.conf` then restart `sudo systemctl reload apache2`

I followed this link https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

Comment: **but instead i got show a coding from /var/www/html/project/public/index.php**, isnt `public/index.php` the entry point for laravel? what is this "show a coding" that you see, an error message, or plain php code? do the url always contains `index.php` on address bar (solved with installing apache `mod_rewrite`)? do you have php installed properly (it should be as long as your phpmyadmin runs fine)? do you have configured the `.env` file? is the dependecies installed in `vendor` folder already (solved through [`composer update`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u))?

Comment: @BagusTesa yes ```/public/index.php``` one of entry point for laravel, what i meant showing coding is literally plain php. My ubuntu server was on separate computer. When i entered the ip address of that computer like ```192.168.0.5```  it run `/public/index.php``` but literally plain php. i did check my php using ```php -v``` and it show 7.x.x. and i did download the vendor via ```composer install``` and updated it using ```composer update``` and ```sudo cp /var/www/html/project/.env.example /var/www/html/project/.env``` and update it.

Comment: it seems the `index.php` is served as plain text, your php havent loaded into the apache. could you check on `httpd.conf` for anything that says php? in the past, to make life easier, i just slap in LAMPP stack instead of installing them manually..

Comment: My apache2 doesn’t come with ```httpd.conf``` like stated on the link but i searched and everything built in on ```apache2.conf```. But either way what am i looking for? And I’m installing my mysql using ```sudo apt-get install mysql-server``` is it any different?

Comment: no, no, its unrelated to mysql server. i just doing checklist based on previous [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/4648586). based on your comment on the answer below, it seems php only not executed on your laravel folder. do you have `<directory>` definition for the public folder, beside the `<virtualhost>` thing?

Comment: I’m not really sure what do you mean by  ```<directory>``` but I don’t think there’s

Answer (score 0):

As you had listed you had already installed the apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin. According to me you are not installing the php on your ubuntu server. Try for checking the

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

If not then you can install by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common
```

And by following command you can download the most commonly used php extensions:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl php7.2-gd php7.2-json php7.2-mbstring php7.2-intl php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml php7.2-zip
```

After that you can install and setup the firewall for security purpose. And don't forget to protect your phpmyadmin page from direct opening.

Comment: I already did download the php following this link <a> https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/php.html </a> And installed every extension and I’ve checked <?php phpinfo(); ?> it worked as well. i just forgot to mentioned it.

Comment: Which php version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

> change .dev to .qa

google chrome update prohibits to use .dev locally.